# Rust Reqwest 10x Slower Than Postman & Firefox

Tags: http, rust, rust-tokio, reqwest

I was testing the performance of [reqwest](https://docs.rs/reqwest/latest/reqwest/) in Rust but somehow the `response.text().await` is taking a good 1-3 seconds to complete. I have tested the exact same page with postman and firefox and it only takes 100-300ms. I have tried multiple times and every single time Postman & Firefox are faster.

I have tried using Hyper as well with `.aggregate()` and have tried using reqwest's `.bytes()` and `.chunk()` and they are all just as slow. The interesting thing is that `.send().await` takes the normal 100-300ms as it's supposed to. Calling `.content_length()` is also perfectly efficient. I also tried using Javascript's `fetch()` and calling `await response.json()`, but this is most certainly faster.

Also this has nothing to do with the release build as manually running the release exe is just as slow. Rust and reqwest are also fully up to date.

Here is the code:

```rs
use std::time::Instant;

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let client = reqwest::Client::new();

    let response = client
        .get("https://registry.npmjs.org/react")
        .send()
        .await
        .unwrap();

    let now = Instant::now();
    let data = response.text().await;
    let elapsed = now.elapsed();

    println!("{}ms", elapsed.as_millis());
}
```

Using `reqwest::blocking` also does not make a difference:

```rs
use std::time::Instant;

fn main() {
    let now = Instant::now();
    let data = reqwest::blocking::get("https://registry.npmjs.org/react")
        .unwrap()
        .text()
        .unwrap();
    let elapsed = now.elapsed();

    println!("{}ms", elapsed.as_millis());
}
```

The time the request takes does decrease if I request an endpoint with less data. For example https://registry.npmjs.org/react/is-even takes 300ms with reqwest, but still 70ms with Postman.

Any ideas what's causing this?

Comment: I am not able to reproduce. Both about 350ms overall for `/react` and about 120ms overall for `/is-even` from my machine. My external HTTP client is sometimes quite a bit faster (up to 100ms faster) but that was only when it re-used the connection and thus skipped the TLS handshake cost. But even that wouldn't explain the 3 seconds in your case. Are you sure your Rust code is running under the same network conditions as Firefox and Postman (i.e. VPN or Proxy or extra firewall)?

Comment: Yeah I am sure, just to make sure I also disabled VPNs in my Windows settings and tried again. What's really weird to me is that using curl produces very similar loading times, however firefox does it 5x faster. I've made sure it's not caching by requesting a new package, but firefox is certainly faster. There's probably something simple I'm missing here haha

Comment: Oh and another note - I tried the same thing on Fedora instead of Windows and it took the same amount of time

Comment: Firefox passes `accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br` to which registry.npmjs.org responds with gzip-ed data (`content-encoding: gzip`) which can significantly reduce the size of the payload. Passing that takes the request on my machine from 350ms down to ~240ms and then again if the TLS connection is reused, that can get down to ~120ms total. BTW, reqwest has a `"gzip"` feature that will parse it for you.

Comment: Fascinating! I actually was just reading the [registry docs](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/responses/package-metadata.md) and they mentioned the `Accept: application/vnd.npm.install-v1+json; q=1.0, application/json; q=0.8, */*` header. This appears to do the exact same thing and makes the search 2x faster. Factoring in that you probably have a faster internet than me and might be closer to a distribution server this makes total sense! I've also found a way that I can use `{registry}/{package}/{version}` instead to get considerably smaller body sizes. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are actually a lot of factors that lead to this unexpected result. Here are our findings.

- You can use the `application/vnd.npm.install-v1+json; q=1.0, application/json; q=0.8, */*` header (as per the [NPM Registry Docs](https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md)) to significantly reduce the size of the payload and make the request faster. You can also do `Content-Encoding: gzip` however this is quite a bit slower.
- There is likely some server side caching involved with the Firefox headers which is possibly why it is so fast even when browser caching is turned off. When clearing the cache and cookies an expected response time is achieved.
- It is possible that because I live in a remote area, the closest distribution center is quite far away making my response times a bit slower
- Using `GET·/{package}/{version}` instead of `GET·/{package}` in addition to the header is a far better solution if possible in your application.

Note that these findings are not 100% certain but are speculation. I will update this answer if I find more information. Happy coding!